# How to select two buttons in a screen at the same time in UWP

Tags: button, uwp

I used button PointerFocus event to set the button border. Need to set border on two buttons in the same screen. Is There a way to set the border of one button without remove the border from a previously selected button in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

The act of getting focus is unique. In other words, when a control gets focus, the previous control loses focus.

If you need the button to remain selected, you may not need `Button`, but `ToggleButton`.

`ToggleButton` has two states (`selected`/`unselected`), while retaining the appearance of `Button`. You can have multiple `ToggleButton`s selected at the same time.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton) about the `ToggleButton`.

Best regards.